# Recursive Variadic Template Function For N-Dimensional Vector

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, vector, variadic

I've been struggling to figure this one out for a while now, and I just can't seem to do it.

What I would like to do is create a template function that requires any number of char parameter arguments and then a single std::string as the parameter. Example syntax would look like this:

```
nvec<3, std::string> info = string_to_vec<':', ';', '-'>(data);
```

nvec is a recursive template class that creates an n-dimensional vector templated on a certain type. Its code is fairly simple and can be seen here:

```
template <size_t dim, typename T>
struct multidimensional_vector
{
  typedef std::vector<typename multidimensional_vector<dim - 1, T>::type> type;
};

template <typename T>
struct multidimensional_vector<0, T>
{
  typedef T type;
};

template <size_t dim, typename T>
using nvec = typename multidimensional_vector<dim, typename T>::type;
```

However, string_to_vec could require any number of character parameters (but at least one). Then, what it needs to do with this information is return a corresponding n-dimensional string vector with the data inserted as separated by those characters. For example, lets say that the std::string that I pass in looks like this:

```
std::string data = "1:2:3;4:5:6;7:8:9-10:11:12;13:14:15;16:17:18"
```

Then I would expect this function to return an n-dimensional vector (templated on type string) which could accessed like this:

```
info[0][0][0] // = 1
info[1][0][0] // = 10
info[1][1][1] // = 14
info[1][2][2] // = 18
// etc.
```

Although this isn't difficult to do if the size of the vector is known ahead of time (just use a lot of for loops), it becomes very difficult when the data contains an arbitrary number of delimiters (meaning that the vector can be any dimension). **Is this possible to do with recursive variadic templates?** If so, I honestly have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier if delimiters are listed top to bottom, higher level first. If that's OK, then something along these lines:

```
template <char... delims>
struct StringToVecHelper {
    static std::string convert(const std::string& data) { return data; }
};

template <char delim, char... tail>
struct StringToVecHelper<delim, tail...> {

static nvec<sizeof...(tail)+1, std::string> convert(const std::string& data) {
    nvec<sizeof...(tail)+1, std::string> result;
    size_t start = 0;
    for (;;) {
        size_t pos = data.find(delim, start);
        std::string piece(data, start, pos - start);
        result.push_back(StringToVecHelper<tail...>::convert(piece));
        if (pos == std::string::npos) break;
        start = pos + 1;
    }
    return result;
}
};

template <char... delims>
auto string_to_vec(const std::string& data) {
    return StringToVecHelper<delims...>::convert(data);
}
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/RMYANU70200)

Comment: Wow, absolutely fantastic.  It's going to take me a while to fully understand what's going on here, but I'm genuinely impressed.  Great work!

Answer (score 0):

I would use structure which is easier to specialize:

```
template <char... Cs> struct string_to_vec_impl;

template <> struct string_to_vec_impl<>
{
    const std::string& operator()(const std::string& s) const { return s; }
};

template <char C, char...Cs> struct string_to_vec_impl<C, Cs...>
{
    nvec<1 + sizeof...(Cs), std::string> operator()(const std::string& s) const
    {
        std::vector<std::string> words = split(s, C); // split string by character c 
        nvec<1 + sizeof...(Cs), std::string> res;
        for (const auto& word : words) {
            res.push_back(string_to_vec_impl<Cs...>{}(word));
        }
        return res;
    }
};

template <char...Cs>
auto string_to_vec_impl(const std::string& s)
{
    return string_to_vec_impl<Cs...>(s)
}
```

Note:

- I let `split` method as exercise.
- order of delimiter is reversed.